# Why does my dark theme button only turn the border black?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button that makes the whole screen black, and then white if you hit it again. it works its just that when you hit the black one it only does the outlines of the website black ex= here is the link to the [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1znZHMWs7H3UuzXO0fTmGXFAdYNm9ZJJ_/view?usp=sharing) and I just don't know how to make it so the whole background is black.

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color:white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Dark/Light Mode</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle between dark and light mode for this page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
```

Comment: hi try this https://codepen.io/ananyaneogi/pen/zXZyMP

Answer (score 0):

The background of the `body` is being set to black, but the rest of the elements on your page still have white backgrounds. They are rendered over your `body` element, so their background is shown instead.

You could either set their backgrounds to always be transparent `background-color: transparent;` (you will still need to ensure the text color is legible on light and dark themes) or you could include them in the list of elements on which you toggle the `.dark-mode` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make all elements have your black background, just add `*` after class name, this will add your black background to all elements.

If you want to add this background to div's only, just replace `*` with `div`, like `.dark-mode div`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color:white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.dark-mode *{
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Dark/Light Mode</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle between dark and light mode for this page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
```